# In ASP.NET MVC 5, how can I deserialize a complex object from a FormCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there accessible tooling in ASP.NET MVC 5 to take a FormCollection parameter from an `[HttpPost]` action and deserialize it into a given type? Like, `MyModelType myModel = SOMEHOWDSERIALIZE<MyModelType>(formCollection);`?

We have a complex object we've been working with in ASP.NET MVC 5 using the usual EditorFor bindings, and the post ***used to*** look like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyModelAction(MyModelV1 myModel)
{
    // .. process the model here
}
```

Now, we have new versions of the model, and we ***will not be* creating a new route/URL** for posting the new model version payload. The model's properties have sufficient metadata for us to infer its deserialized type, so we can use that from the form fields to decipher which model type to deserialize and execute. So now it looks something like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyModelAction(FormCollection parameters)
{
    switch (parameters["OurVersionDisambiguator"])
    {
        case "V1":
            var myModel_V1 = SOMEHOW_DESERIALIZE<MyModel_V1>(parameters);
            return MyModelAction(myModel_V1);
        case "V2":
            var myModel_V2 = SOMEHOW_DESERIALIZE<MyModel_V2>(parameters);
            return MyModelAction(myModel_V2);
        default: throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[NonAction]
public ActionResult MyModelAction(MyModelV1 myModelV1) 
{
    // process the model
}

[NonAction]
public ActionResult MyModelAction(MyModelV2 myModelV2) 
{
    // process the model
}
```

In the above sample, I infer creating something like the following method, and I'm not sure what to do with it ...

```
T SOMEHOW_DESERIALIZE<T>(FormCollection parameters)
```

I know I could use Activator and Reflection and manually spoonfeed the deserialization "by hand", but since ASP.NET MVC normally does it automatically for us when we don't use `FormCollection`, there is surely such tooling we can invoke as a one-liner?

Note that in the above samples, the processing must continue to have access to the Request context, as there may be file upload streams to be processed in the same request.

Comment: Do these classes share a base class?  Or could you have the argument to the action be an object then inspect it's type from there to make decisions?  MVC uses model binders to deserialize the various inputs into your models.  You could make a custom model binder to figure out the typing then run that through one of the standard binders to do the deserialization automatically.

Comment: "Do these classes share a base class?"
The classes do not (necessarily) share a base class; their properties could be completely different and/or incompatible.
"MVC uses model binders to deserialize...You could make a custom model binder"
Thanks for the pointer/direction :)

Comment: Unfortunately every "Custom Model Binder" tutorial I've found spells out to do manual property-by-property, field-by-field propagation. Honestly I'm just looking for something as simple as Json's DeserializeObject<T> but for FormCollection, why is this so difficult to find? Something is surely baked in Microsoft's code somewhere.

Comment: What I've done in the past was to make a custom model binder that inspected the form collection for some indicator of type and then invoked the other model binders by giving them the type it should deserialize to.  Look at this to give you an idea of what you might be able to do [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504824/how-to-call-default-model-binding-from-custom-binder-in-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504824/how-to-call-default-model-binding-from-custom-binder-in-webapi).

Answer (score 3):

Since I was looking for a simple one-liner to bind the FormCollection to a model of type-known-at-runtime, having a custom model binder isn't much of a solution. Fortunately, the baked-in functionality I was looking for was `TryUpdateModel(..)`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyModelAction(FormCollection parameters)
{
    switch (parameters["OurVersionDisambiguator"])
    {
        case "V1":
            var myModel_V1 = new MyModel_V1();
            var hasModelStateError /* ignoring */ =
                TryUpdateModel(myModel_V1, parameters.ToValueProvider());
            return MyModelAction(myModel_V1);
        case "V2":
            var myModel_V2 = new MyModel_V2();
            var hasModelStateError /* ignoring */ =
                TryUpdateModel(myModel_V2, parameters.ToValueProvider());
            return MyModelAction(myModel_V2);
        default: throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[NonAction]
public ActionResult MyModelAction(MyModelV1 myModelV1) 
{
    // process the model
}

[NonAction]
public ActionResult MyModelAction(MyModelV2 myModelV2) 
{
    // process the model
}
```